# php gzcompress encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding

Problem :

Hi, I used gzcompress function of php to compress a google page requested from php curl. I stored it as a html file but on gzuncompress some characters are not decoded correctly.The page was from google lietuvos.

code :

```
// Encoding used in curl request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip,deflate'); 

//Compressing
gzcompress($res['page'],9);

// Uncompressing
gzuncompress($data);
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything?
Thank you.enter image description here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the little information we have, I assume that this is a problem with newlines and with the encoding having the character `"\0"` (`null` character) somewhere.

What you can do is the following:

Compress the page and encode to base64:

```
base64_encode(gzcompress($res['page'],9));
```

To decompress, decode from base64:

```
gzuncompress(base64_decode($data));
```

This will ensure that everything will be written and read as-is, with around 33% of overhead.

There are other solutions for this problem, but this is the easiest.