# What's the encoding should I use to "gzuncompress()" in node.js?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm converting my code from PHP to `node.js`, and I need to convert a part of my code where there's the `gzuncompress()` function.

For that I'm using `zlib.inflateSync`. But I don't know which **encoding** I should use to create the **buffer** and so to have the *same* result of **php**

Here's what I do with php to decompress a **string:**

```
gzuncompress(substr($this->raw, 8))
```

and here's what I've tried in node.js

```
zlib.inflateSync(new Buffer(this.raw.substr(8), "encoding"))
```

So what **encoding** should I use to make `zlib.inflateSync` returns the same data as `gzuncompress` ?

Comment: Hi, did you get the answer you were looking for? I am facing the same issue and can't find a single solution.

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026768/php-gzcompress-encoding-issue

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what would be exact encoding here however this repo has some PHP translations for node.js (https://github.com/gamalielmendez/node-fpdf/blob/master/src/PHP_CoreFunctions.js). According to this repo, the following could work:

```
const gzuncompress = (data) => {
    const chunk = (!Buffer.isBuffer(data)) ? Buffer.from(data, 'binary') : data
    const Z1 = zlib.inflateSync(chunk)
    return Z1.toString('binary')//'ascii'
}
```